# Jpa entity relationship caused endless loop

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I am using spring data jpa to build my project. There is a User entity and a Biz entity.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserInformation belongUser;//所属用户
```

This code above is part of Biz class.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "belongUser")
private Set<BizInformation> bizs = new HashSet<BizInformation>();
```

And this is part of User class

The Problem is when I get a UserInfomation via RESTful api, it returns a BizInfo,then inside the BizInfo it returns the UserInfomation,and finally caused a StackOverFlow Exception.

How can I solve this? thanks.

Comment: an endless loop somewhere but you don't say. Seemingly this is JSON which is absolutely nothing to do with the JPA API

Comment: @DN1 this is known JSON serialiser behaviour (many people say: error, other: feature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem cause by the bidirectional relationships. you can use 
**@JsonManagedReference** and **@JsonBackReference**

- @JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that
  gets serialized normally.
- @JsonBackReference is the back part of reference – it will be omitted
  from serialization.

in your case you can add @JsonManagedReference in User class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "belongUser")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<BizInformation> bizs = new HashSet<BizInformation>();
```

and @JsonBackReference for Biz class which will omit the UserInformation serialization

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonBackReference
private UserInformation belongUser;//所属用户
```

you can also use @JsonIgnore for the class that you want to omit the serialization

more detail : [jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Comment: nice question and nicer answer

Comment: This is a very common scenario. People trying to marshall/unmarshall entities into json generally forget about the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("bizs")
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserInformation belongUser;
```